# Cannot close binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary

I tried to make a program that reads `ELEM` structures from keyboard and writes them to a file (file.bin) and then writes unique items to another file (aux.bin). The problem is that it can not close opened files in `void function()`, can you please tell me what I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[80];
    int p;
}ELEM;

void clear_stdin()
{
    char str[255];
    fgets(str,255,stdin);
}

int create()
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    int c;
    int n=0;
    ELEM s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","wb");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("create(): Could not open file.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?:\n1 - yes\n2 - no\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if (c==1)
    {
        printf("Name=");
        clear_stdin();
        fgets(s.name,80,stdin);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",&s.p);
        fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        n++;
    }
    else
        d=1;
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
    return n;
}

void show(int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    ELEM s;
    int i=0;
    if(n==0)
        return;
    f=fopen("file.bin","rb");
    while(i<n)
    {
        fread(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        puts(s.name);
        printf("\t%d\n",s.p);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int add(int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    int c;
    ELEM s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","ab");
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("add(): Could not open file.bin for append\n");
        return;
    }
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?:\n1 - yes\n2 - no\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    if (c==1)
    {
        printf("Name=");
        clear_stdin();
        fgets(s.name,80,stdin);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",&s.p);
        fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        n++;
    }
    else
        d=1;
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
    return n;
}


void func(int n)
{
    FILE *f,*g;
    ELEM v[20],w;
    int i=0,j,k,x=0,s,gn=0,test;
    f=fopen("file.bin","rb");
    g=fopen("aux.bin","wb");
    if((g==NULL)||(f==NULL))
    {
        if(g==NULL)
            printf("function() : Could not open aux.bin for write\n");
        if(f==NULL)
            printf("function() : Could not open file.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        fread(&v[i],sizeof(ELEM),1,f);

        i++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(k=j+1;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(v[j].p==v[k].p)
                x=1;

        }
        if(x==0)
        {
            s=strcmp(v[j].name,v[k].name);
            if(s!=0)
            {
                fwrite(&v[j],sizeof(ELEM),1,g);
                fread(&w,sizeof(ELEM),1,g);

                gn++;
            }
        }
        x=0;
    }
    test=fclose(g);
    if(test!=0)
        printf("function() : failed to closed file g\n");
    test=fclose(f);
    if(test!=0)
        printf("function() : failed to closed file f\n");
    g=fopen("aux.bin","rb");
    if(g==NULL)
    {
        printf("function() : Could not open aux.bin for read\n");
        return;
    }
    if(gn==0)
        return;
    i=0;
    while(i<gn)
    {
        fread(&w,sizeof(ELEM),1,g);
        puts(w.name);
        printf("\t%d\n",w.p);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(g);
}

int main()
{
    int k=0,r,n;
    do{
        printf("1 - create file\n2 - add elements to file\n3 - show elements\n4 - put unique elements in another file\n5 - exit program\n");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        switch(r)
        {
            case 1 : n=create(); break;
            case 2 : n=add(n); break;
            case 3 : show(n); break;
            case 4 : func(n); break;
            case 5 : k=1; break;
            default : printf("Command unrecognized!\n");
        }
    } while(k==0);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I edited the code

aux.bin was never created, that's why it freezes at `fread(&w,sizeof(ELEM),1,g);`
But why it can't create aux.bin ?
I don't get any error messages but when I open the project folder, there's just file.bin.

---

EDIT:
I switched form MinGW and Visual Studio to gcc, and now it creates both files, everything works excepting **fflush(stdin)** . I replaced **gets(s.name);** to **fgets(s.name,80,stdin);** .

---

EDIT:
I replaced fflush(stdin) with a function that clears the stdin and now it works flawlessly with gcc in linux.
In windows it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be expecting your file handle pointers to become `NULL` when you close the file, that's not true.

Note that the `fclose()` function takes the pointer (an argument of type `FILE *`), so all it gets is the pointer's value, it *cannot* change the caller's pointer. For that to be possible, you would have to call it with a `FILE **`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

It's your responsibility to set the pointer to `NULL` after the `fclose()` call, if (and only if)  `fclose()` said it succeeded, by returning 0. See [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose) for details.

Comment: Thank you, now I know what to expect when I close a file, and how to use fclose().

Comment: It closes the files succesfully, but after **printf("function() : step2: feof(g)=%d\n",feof(g));** it does nothing, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user1187554: You've used the wrong file pointer in the fread() call that follows the `printf("function() : step2: feof(g)=%d\n",feof(g));`. You have used `f` but it should be `g`.

Comment: Thank you! but it still doesn't work... and **aux.bin** was never created.

Comment: You mean you get "Could not open aux.bin for write"?

Comment: no, but when i open the project folder, there is only **file.bin**

Comment: @Cristi: It could be a platform restriction. "AUX" is a reserved file name on Windows. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx